# Transparency on text background-color without overlap

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background color on my heading, which follows the text inline, and is semi transparent, but I want to keep the line spacing as is, whilst avoiding the color background overlap between the lines. The `br`'s are for demonstration purposes.

```
<h2>
<span>I like<br>Turtles<br>Do<br>You?</span>
</h2>
```

This fiddle explains all: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisjimallen/teFdZ/105/

I've tried what I can think of, the closest solution is to inline block the span tag, but then it becomes a box.

Comment: remove the padding will do I guess...

Comment: seems to me that @kukkuz has a point - the line-height must be the size of the font plus any padding applied (and an additional couple of pixels).  If you want to keep that line height, then you will need to reduce the top bottom padding to 1px: http://jsfiddle.net/teFdZ/113/ (in chrome - may be different for other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Is this you lookin for? Just play with padding.
padding:1px 10px 0px 10px; clockwise (top-right-bottom-left)

```css
h2   { font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:30px}
h2 span {
  color:#fff;
  line-height:35px;
  display:inline;
  background-color: rgba(252, 108, 33, 0.8);
  padding:1px 10px 0px 10px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h2>
<span>I Like<br>Turtles<br>Do<br>You?</span>
</h2>
```